# Can a lone black hole in a closed Universe evaporate?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, universe, curvature, hawking-radiation

If there is a closed Universe which only has a black hole in it, can that black hole evaporate?  As the black hole evaporates, it gives off energy, which will eventually come back and be re-absorbed into the black hole.  So if it exists in such a closed Universe, can it still evaporate?

Comment: Hawking radiation leaves the horizon above escape velocity.

Comment: And if the Universe is closed, won't that radiation travel around the Universe, ultimately returning to the black hole?

Comment: If the universe is closed, then it is not empty.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer In what sense? I can picture a flat static vacuum $\mathbf{T}^3 \times \mathbf{R}$. Btw. I think the problem is we would have to find a black-hole solution with such asymptotics and then apply the quasiclassical analysis, but I doubt we even have have such a solution to start with.

Comment: In a universe where the whole universe is in thermal equilibrium with one black hole, the universe without a black hole is the much, much, much more likely statistical case, so for most of the time there will be no black hole in that universe. For an expanding universe the black hole would never re-occur, for a closed universe it would, but only on absolutely unimaginable timescales.

Comment: @Void: you can only do that gluing in Minkowski space due to the fact that it has so many nice Killing vectors.  Add a black hole, and it's nontrivial to identify one side of the universe with another without leaving some sort of singularity in the seam.

Answer (score 3):

Even if we could assume an empty closed universe, the answer depends on both, the size of the black hole and the size of the universe. The smaller the black hole the faster it evaporates, and the larger the universe the longer it takes the radiation to come back, so the black hole can be evaporated before the radiation comes back.

Comment: Could a Universe with two black holes revolving around a common center fast enough cause a closed Universe in which the black holes are large enough that they couldn't evaporate (i.e. they exchange radiation fast enough to keep their size)?

Comment: It will not change things much, because most of the radiation will not be absorbed by the second black hole, only the portion emitted towards it will fall, the rest will travel as in a single universe black hole.